# cant format NVME drive(Write protected)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure, nvme

The hard drive that's in question is a **Samsung 970 Evo**. Essentially, I was working on a project at home and kicked the cable that the PC was connected to and cold disconnected my PC while it was running. It never came back on after that. I was working on it throughout the weekend trying many different things ( like windows repair, disk repair, Terminal repairs through CHKDSK commands, and trying to work through DISKPART with other commands plus tried a few applications to see if I could format the drive, or fix the bad sectors etc ), but to no avail.

Every single thing I've tried, always results in "drive is write protected". I went ahead and purchased another drive and had to reinstall everything over again. This said, I was able to get some data out of it so i was trying to format it so that i could use it in another system but like i mentioned, its not working.

Is there anything i can do to not lose the drive?

Thank you in advance

Comment: When an SSD shows as *read-only*, it is one sign of failure. See https://www.diskinternals.com/partition-recovery/ssd-failure/ for suggestions, e.g. "You can also try running SFC or chkdsk, but there is no guarantee that this will help." Also, see https://www.diskpart.com/articles/ssd-will-not-format-0310.html . Also see https://www.laptopmag.com/news/windows-10-update-may-be-damaging-your-ssd-heres-how-to-stop-it about Windows 10 SSD issue